# Android: Problems to show a new fragment after click in a item of a list

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments

I have a list of items(Stations.java) and I'm trying to implement a click in one of the item to show all the details. It´s showing properly the list of items but I get an error on the setOnItemClickListener when I try to redirect to the StationDetails.

Error:

> android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class

But I think the error is when I execute the intent. I mean something wrong with that.

Below is the code:

```
public class Stations extends Fragment {

final String TAG = "Debugging";
final String Url = "...";

private ListView lstStations;
ArrayList<Station> dataset;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.station_list, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    lstStations = (ListView)getView().findViewById(R.id.lstStations);
    RequestStations();
    lstStations.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            getActivity();

            TextView textViewName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_row_station);
            String stationName = textViewName.getText().toString();

            for(Station obj : dataset) {
                if(obj.getName() == stationName){
                    Log.d("############","Items " + stationName);

                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), StationDetails.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        }

    });

   }
... }
```

Below is the Fragment I'm trying to show.

```
public class StationDetails extends Fragment {

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.station_details, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
 }
}
```

Below is the manifest, maybe that can help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MyActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you declared stationDetails.class in your manifest??/

```
NO!!
```

the answer you will give is that because its a fragment...

so why do you try to open or start it like an Activity???
do this

```
 Fragment station = new StationDetails();
 FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
 transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, station);
 transaction.commit();
```

the reason is because android treats it like its an activity but its not so it ends up with that error.. fragments runs on activities so you can embed fragments into activities..
EDIT: its fine what you want to do, but if you want to open an activity which i guess is StattionDetails.class then i suggest you declare it in the manifest like this

```
<activity
    android:name=".StationDetails"
    android:label="your stationdetails name" >        
</activity>
```

this should be a child of the application tag-(paste it below the .mainactivity)
and also in your StationDetails.class change the extends to Activity like this

```
public class StationDetails extends Activity{
```

with this your StationDetails class is an activity..but if you want to treat StationDetails as fragment then use the first method
let me know if it helps

Comment: I have tested and it's not working. I'm new working with android so I really don't know how works everything. Let me explain you what I want. I have a Fragment with a list of invoices, now I want implement when an user click in one item then show all the details. After see your comment maybe what I have to do is open in the intent a new Activity in the onclicklistener and not a Fragment (I know it's wrong my code after your answer), isn't it? and if is it right, how can I do that?

Comment: what didnt work? openning the fragment? ok, well im editting the answer check edited answer@gon250

Comment: Problem now is I can see the new fragment but it's overlapped in the old fragment.

Comment: yeah.. its because of the add code  {transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, station);} so change it and make it replace {transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, station);} the code are in parenthesis @gon250